# Image analysis - fiber recognition

Tags: filters, image-processing

I am completely new to image analysis. Do you know how to binarize this image in such a way to get the fibers only?

[image]

A step by step procedure would be awesome, but any hint is appreciated as well. I can use Matlab, .NET and I am open to any other tool.

PS: At this [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387801/image-analysis-fiber-recognition) you can find the same question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is your friend. Basicaly it deals with straight lines (and almost all fibers in your example are straight). You can find open source implementation in OpenCV ([here is doc + result example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html#houghlines2)).

Moreover there is some generalizations that able to detect custom shapes.
P.S. Since you're using C#, [OpenCV wrapper](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) could be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the results are not good if you do not use a proper low pass filter as you clearly stated that you do not want noise. Also, for usage in Hough Transform, you have lot of option to change in order to detect. Length of line segment and angle of the line segments, you may adjust what you want. 
 [image: Hough Transform Result with little noise]

Answer (score 1):

I concur about Hough transform, but before it would be good to pass image through the edge detector ([Canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) is preferable and available in OpenCV)